# How to set compression quality for webp encoding in Firefox

Tags: firefox, canvas, browser, webp

Firefox 96+ [supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/96) `webp` encoding in canvas functions e.g. `HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()`

Nice, `webp` supports transparency.

Trying that out it I can't set the quality level, like for jpeg.

`canvas.toBlob(function(blob){ /*...*/ }, 'image/jpeg', 0.70); // JPEG at 70% quality`

works

`canvas.toBlob(function(blob){ /*...*/ }, 'image/webp', 0.70); // WEBP at 70% quality`

doesn't work. (works in Chromium)

It seems there is only one compression setting, something like 92% compared to converting CLI (`convert -quality 92 img.png img.webp`)

Also tried 70 instead of 0.70.

What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

[Bug 1750475](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1750475)

**Fixed in 98 (beta)**

Answer (score 1):

No reason is stated, but for the time being [Firefox supports the quality parameter only for jpeg](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/canvas/CanvasRenderingContextHelper.cpp#264)

Comment: Thx for pointing that out. Taking into account that the compression level is worse than cwebp default, this new implementation is a bit of a disappointment.

Comment: I implemented the webp encoder in Firefox and it supports a quality parameter. My guess is, that the dots are just not connected somewhere and I missed it

Comment: @Fuzzyma. Thx, Then, I guess it can be fixed in the near future ;)